# Using PCSCD with ACR122U error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, usb-device

I try to use the ACR122U with PCSCD with mfcuk bu on my PCSCD terminal I have a recurrent error :

```
00400285 ccid_usb.c:747:WriteUSB() write failed (3/4): -1 LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
00000063 ifdwrapper.c:371:IFDStatusICC() Card not transacted: 612
00000034 eventhandler.c:335:EHStatusHandlerThread() Error communicating to: ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 00 00
00000063 ccid_usb.c:1213:InterruptRead() libusb_submit_transfer failed: -1
```

I don't from where it comes and how to fix it...